# Adding a column to a union select statement results with more result rows

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I made a database for stock management system. 
For some reporting i need union of two queries from two different tables, 
after writing a select statement I noticed that results are lacking one row.
After adding one more column the missing row appeared. 
I am providing print screens of queries and results.

[image: initial query][image: after adding one more column in queries]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Use plain text in code blocks instead. Read: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: OK, sorry i did it. I thought it was a good way to show query and results in the same shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Union All instead of Union. As you are using Union here it will will eliminate duplicate rows from your output.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't surprising.

`UNION` removes duplicate rows.  So, when you add a new column you make rows that were the same different.  For instance:

Table1

```
x    y
1    'a'
1    'b'
```

Table2

```
x    y
1    'c'
2    'd'
```

The following query:

```
select x from table1 
union
select x from table2
```

returns:

```
1
2
```

However, including `y`:

```
select x, y from table1 
union
select x, y from table2
```

You get four rows:

```
x    y
1    'a'
1    'b'
1    'c'
2    'd'
```

If you used `union all`, you would get the same number of rows in both cases.  In the first case, you would see duplicate rows in the result set.

This answers the question that you asked.  If you want a particular result set, ask a *new* question is sample data, desired results, and your queries *as text* in the question.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this explanation helps a lot. Garvit's solution is working it too, hence I don't need any more columns.

Comment: @djoleasterix . . . You should note that I mention `union all` in this answer, which was posted earlier than that answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Didn't see that